# How to send a C2D Direct method from the Node.js SDK to a remote device?

Tags: node.js, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying to connect my local Node.js API to Azure IOT Hub and send direct methods to a remote device.

When sending the direct method directly through the Azure portal, it works like a charm. However, when attempting to do the same through the API, I get a `Timed out waiting for the response from device" message.`

Here is the code I tried so far, using the `azure-iothub` library:

```js
"use strict";

exports.sendDirectMethod = async (req, res) => {    
    const connectionString = process.env.IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING;    
    const deviceId = "HW2";
    const serviceClient = iothub.Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
    const payload = {        
        methodName: "GetAllLockerStatus_method",
        responseTimeoutInSeconds: 30,
        payload: JSON.stringify({ MessageID: 1,}),
    };
    serviceClient.invokeDeviceMethod(deviceId, payload, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        } else {
            console.log(`Response status: ${result.status}`);
            console.log(`Response payload: ${result.payload}`);
        }
    });
};
```

Any idea on how to resolve the issue is welcome, as I am quite stuck a the moment. Thanks!

I tried many different solutions to end up with the code I proposed above. It appears I am able to connect to the IoT Hub but the Device does not recognise the message.

Comment: tested in the Azure portal and with code but getting time out error

Comment: tried with [MQTT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods) and [git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device?pivots=programming-language-nodejs)

Comment: with [mqtt](https://i.imgur.com/gIZ9eGk.png) this might [help you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device?pivots=programming-language-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

There's a quickstart in the IoT Hub documentation that shows you how to do this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device?pivots=programming-language-nodejs

You can find the device and service sample code here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-node/tree/master/iot-hub/Quickstarts

I don't see anything obvious wrong with your service code. Do you get any errors from the device code? Are you sure the method name is the same in both the device and service code? It might be helpful if you shared your device code as well.

Dominic